# PDO não mostra erros

Tags: php, pdo

Meu código de conexão não mostra erros, qual é o problema, pesquisei em vários lugares e não encontrei nada a respeito:

```
class Connect {

    protected static $db;

    public function __construct() {}

    public static function Database() {

        if (is_null(self::$db)) {
            try {
                self::$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . HOSTNAME . ';dbname=' . DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return self::$db;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para exibir ou ocultar erros, os parâmetros devem ser passados ao PHP, logo se der erro na lib PDO, serão exibidos. Coloque este código no início do arquivo que deverá conseguir ver os erros:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Agora apareceu, grato...